# EJS Parsing JSON Array within JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

Please help me, I'm trying to parse json data from mongodb. 
I need to access the inner json object **activities-heart** and **heartRateZones** to html table.

**Json data**

```
{
   "_id":{ },
   "refreshToken":"dba7449db19d20ce77f5a247ef2d9ac06e3387464c011b0424db1064bcfce503",
   "profile":{
      "provider":"fitbit",
      "_json":{
         "activities-heart":[
            {
               "customHeartRateZones":[ ],
               "dateTime":"today",
               "heartRateZones":[
                  {
                     "caloriesOut":2.80434,
                     "max":84,
                     "min":30,
                     "minutes":2,
                     "name":"Out of Range"
                  },
                  {
                     "caloriesOut":0,
                     "max":118,
                     "min":84,
                     "minutes":0,
                     "name":"Fat Burn"
                  },
                  {
                     "caloriesOut":0,
                     "max":143,
                     "min":118,
                     "minutes":0,
                     "name":"Cardio"
                  },
                  {
                     "caloriesOut":0,
                     "max":220,
                     "min":143,
                     "minutes":0,
                     "name":"Peak"
                  }
               ],
               "value":"61.86"
            }
         ],
```

**javaScript for parsing json object**

```
<% for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="quotes">
      <span><%= quotes[i].profile._json.activities-heart %></span>

    </li>
```

I am a beginner to the ejs.
I'm getting "heart is not defined" error.

Comment: your snippet provides no proof that 'quotes' is an array. makes it harder to help you. 'activities-heart' is an array though so you probably want to put a number after that as you did here 'quotes[i]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS treats `activities-heart` as `activities minus heart`, so it shows **heart is not defined** because it doesn't see any `heart` variable (no worries, everything is fine with your body). Try this:

```
<span><%=
    var datetime = quotes[i].profile._json['activities-heart'].dateTime;
    var cardioZone = quotes[i].profile._json['activities-heart'].heartRateZones[2];
    var cardioMinHR = cardioZone.min;
%></span>
```

Comment: Thank u so much but how can access the object of activities-heart(heartRateZone,datetime,max ,min etc)

Comment: Edited, check this out